# How to let screenshot show a mouse pointer on Mojave and Catalina?

Tags: macos, mojave, screen-capture

I think in Mojave and up, we can press <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> to show a menu of what to capture on screen and the Options.

There are options for a 5 second or 10 second timer, and one to "Show Mouse Pointer".  But if I use a 10 second timer and "Show Mouse Pointer", the mouse pointer is not in the screenshot? (The one I tried was to get a region of the screen). How to make it work?

P.S. I experimented some more. If I do a full screen capture, the mouse pointer was there. But if it is a window or region capture, then the mouse pointer wasn't there.

Comment: I tested on my side. You can simply use the same function that you have mentioned in your question. However, I have used an option "Capture Entire Screen"

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot under Catalina does not have this problem, went taking timed full screen captures. If only a selected portion or window is needed, then take a screenshot of a selected portion of the full screen image. This can result in a monotonous and time consuming process. However, the Screenshot application includes a record feature, that can be used when many screen captures are needed. You can then playback, pause and capture whole screens, windows or portions. Below is one example.

[image]

### Example of the Wrong and Right Way to Capture a Window.

**The images below were taken using the Grab application from High Sierra.**

Grab was used to capture a Finder window. The image is shown below. The problem here is the window does not have focus.

[image]

Next, Grap was used to capture a selection which included the Finder window, as shown below. Still no focus.

[image]

Finally, a timed capture was taken of the entire screen. The the delay was used to give focus to the Finder window. Next, a selection was captured from this image. The result was the correct image shown below.

[image]

**Below is an example where the Screenshot application was is used from Catalina.**

First, a two captures of a Finder window were taken, as shown below. The first image was taken without a timer. The second was taken with a 5 second timer, so focus could be given to the window. In both cases, neither window has focus.

[image]
[image]

Next, a capture of a selected portion was taken, which included the window, as shown below. Here the image is correct. *So at least Apple has fixed one problem*.

[image]

Finally, two captures were taken. The first involved the timed full screen, then a portion of the first image. The second image is shown below. You can see this image is also correct.

[image]

**Below is an example where the Screenshot application is used from Catalina. This time a screen pointer is included**

Below is a selected portion taken with a timer. The screen pointer is not included.

[image]
Again, two captures were taken. The first involved the timed full screen, then a portion of the first image. The second image is shown below. You can see the image below includes the screen pointer.

[image]

### Conclusions

The capture portion of Screenshot works for images which do not require inclusion of the screen pointer. When the screen pointer needs to be included, you may still need to resort to the two image approach that Grab required.

Comment: so you mean your "still image" screenshot actually contained the mouse pointer?

Comment: @nonopolarity: Yes, I had to redo the image. You have to place the mouse pointer in the lower right of the screen before clicking. Otherwise two pointers will appear. (Actually, the second pointer still appears, if you look closely.)

Comment: please see PS in question. It had to be a full screen capture for it to work.

Comment: @nonopolarity: This is old news to anyone with experience. Step one: Take a timed full screen capture. Step two: Capture a region from the full screen image. This can be a monotonous and time consuming process, but sometimes this is the only way to get the job done.

Comment: So you mean the mouse pointer is only to be in a full screen capture but not in window or region capture?  Then I suppose the Apple Support webpage should state: "We say it will capture the mouse pointer, but people with experience should know it means for full screen capture only"

Comment: @nonopolarity: Yes. Apple probably decided to release the Snapshot application knowing this problem existed. Still, Snapshot is an improvement over Grab. If for no other reason, the focus problem is now fixed. I updated my answer, in an effort to explain this.